# Do you know the exact model and use of this rotorcraft?

Tags: helicopter, usa, aircraft-identification, rotorcraft

[image]

I've tried to identify this. Someone suggested it is a [Bell 206](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_206), possibly a Jet or Long Ranger. I disagree.

I think it is a US Coast Guard helicopter. It flew over my house in Mobile, Alabama. It's been difficult identifying from this angle I photographed it.

Comment: Could you please explain why you do not think it is a Bell 206?

Comment: Because the photo that  I've seen of a Bell 206 didn't match up with this one. If you look at the nose you will see the glass above and below center piece dividing them. You can see the blade on the left thru the top glass.. While I realize there are variations of the Bell 206 (Example-TS 57 Sea Ranger) , I'm still not sold until someone finds this particular plane.

Comment: I'm not versed in military markings, but do the star/bars symbol underneath denote it is not a civilian aircraft?

Comment: Also, you saw it in straight and level flight, so can you check a map and backplot the path?  That may give you an idea of where it was coming from and going to, which could give you somewhere to make inquiries.

Comment: Criggie- according to a photo friend of mine, it has a US Airforce star on the bottom. I haven't varified that as of yet. I believe it was getting ready to land or just took off from a local airport about a mile or two away-Mobile Reginal Airport. I wil check and see if this airport has this type of plane coming and going. Since checking into this I got a Google message pop down on my computer asking if they can have my location. I hope I didn't set off red flags somehow. I'm a photographer and I photograph everything. Especially, planes etc passing over my house.

Answer (score 20):

It's a Bell TH-57, most likely a TH-57C, which is the Navy's variant of the Bell 206 JetRanger.  It's used for VFR and IFR helicopter primary flight training for the Navy and Marine Corps.  Most likely that picture you took was of a TH-57 out of Pensacola NAS on a training flight.  They like to come out to KBFM and Jack Edwards in Gulf Shores to practice flying, pattern work, etc.

[image]

Comment: Carlo -the glass on mine apprears to meet with the center line that divides both top and bottom glass. You can see the blade in the upper left corner. I'm not saying there isn't a variation to the Bell 206 that matches. I just don't believe the TS 57 Sea Ranger is the one that does.

Comment: Carlo, I appreciate your help. It was flying low enough to believe it had just taken off or getting ready to land. We have Mobile Regional Airport about a 1-2 miles from my house.

Comment: If by glass you mean the forward windshield meeting with the lower transparencies, it doesn't; it's just from than angle, it's difficult to discern the nose of the aircraft from that angle; and the nose glare shield will appear to look like glass from than angle in the sun as well.  You will often see TH-57s parked out there at KBFM at Signature Flight Service near the Airbus hangars.

Comment: Your very first statement above your photo states as follows-
It's a Bell TH-57, most likely a TH-57C, which is the Navy's variant of the Bell 206 JetRanger. It's used for VFR and IFR helicopter primary flight training for the Navy and Marine Corps

Comment: ...........and??????

Comment: YOU DIDN'T look close enough at my photo. The stars and stripes insignia on the undercarriage stand for US AIRFORCE. might want to check for a rotocraft that has glass above meeting with a divider of the glass below , under that branch of service.

Comment: The US roundel - which is what I'm guessing you mean by 'stars and stripes' - on the belly of the helicopter is common to all US government and military aircraft.  The Army, Navy, Air Force, Marines and Coast Guard all display that roundel on their aircraft.  As for the 'glass', you didn't read my previous comments about the perspective and lighting effects.

Comment: The TH-57s used to be based out of NAS Whiting Field, unless they have moved...

Comment: [On this page](https://invitaminerva45.blogspot.com/2012/03/prestigiosa-us-coast-guard.html) is a photo of a fixed-wing craft clearly bearing the same roundel (on the underside of the starboard wing, and on the tail) and very plainly marked as a USCG asset. So, it's not uniquely an Air Force marking.

Comment: @CCTO it's been standardised for all US military (and the USCG is part of the military) aviation assets for decades, 1950s I think. Only difference is the size, sometimes the colouring (grey scale vs full colour), and that at times the entire thing was surrounded by a thin white border which has since been dropped.